# How much exception vectors should I fill in the firmware?

Tags: assembly, arm, stm32, firmware, thumb

I'm playing with ARM using an STM32F103C8T6 Blue Pill board. According to its [Programming Manual](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/programming_manual/5b/ca/8d/83/56/7f/40/08/CD00228163.pdf/files/CD00228163.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00228163.pdf) (Section 2.3.4 Vector Table), there are a total of 83 exception vectors to be set. However, [this tutorial](https://jacobmossberg.se/posts/2017/01/10/minimalistic-assembler-program-on-stm32-h103.html) only fills the first 6 and [this tutorial](https://github.com/jasLogic/bare-metal-arm/tree/master/4_first_program_and_linker) the first 10. Curiously, I can verify that both firmware executes as expected, despite the absence of a lot of exception handlers.

Just to clarify, below is the very part I am referring to ([link to original file](https://github.com/jasLogic/bare-metal-arm/blob/master/4_first_program_and_linker/main.s)). As you can see, only the first few words get assigned a handler, and all subsequent space is used to hold the `.text` section.

```
.section .isr_vector
.align  2
.global _isr_vector
_isr_vector:
    .long   __StackTop /* we will need this later */
    .long   Reset_Handler
    .long   Default_Handler
    .long   Default_Handler
    .long   Default_Handler
    .long   Default_Handler
    .long   Default_Handler
    .long   0
    .long   0
    .long   0
    .long   0
    .long   Default_Handler
    .long   Default_Handler
    .long   0
    .long   Default_Handler
    .long   Default_Handler
```

This confuses me: what is the least amount of exception handlers I need to fill? In my use case (which is nothing more than a toy project), there are no exceptions to be excepted, so can I just set the Reset Handler?

As a bonus, the Programming Manual specifies that "The least-significant bit of each vector must be 1, indicating that the exception handler is Thumb code." However, the code above clearly doesn't follow this convention, so how does it correctly call the reset handler on boot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.thumb
.global _start
_start:
.word 0x20001000
.word one
.word two
.align
.thumb_func
one:
    b .
two:
    b .

arm-none-eabi-as so.s -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -Ttext=0x08000000 so.o -o so.elf
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D so.elf

so.elf:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

08000000 <_start>:
 8000000:   20001000    andcs   r1, r0, r0
 8000004:   0800000d    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r2, r3}
 8000008:   0800000e    stmdaeq r0, {r1, r2, r3}
    
0800000c <one>:
 800000c:   e7fe        b.n 800000c <one>

0800000e <two>:
 800000e:   e7fe        b.n 800000e <two>
```

First off, _start is not required, you will get a warning, it's easier just to put it in there.

You need to declare the label as a function there are a couple of ways to do this in gnu assembler.  .thumb_func is easy it does not have to be the line just before you can have other stuff between .thumb_func and the label, but the next label is marked a function.

You will see the output of the compiler do something like this (use -save-temps or -S to see the compiler output), there is another way to declare a function in gas, for full sized arm there is a different one you have to use.

You can see when properly declared the tools take care of you and orr the lsbit of the address in the vector table when you don't declare it properly then you get the wrong address in the vector table which won't work.

And as answered minimum is two entries only because you need to have something at offset/address 4.  Note that 0x08000000 maps to 0x00000000 when booting on these STM32 platforms.  The minimum is the reset vector if you don't need any of the others, but being at an offset you need to pad the first four bytes.  Might as well put a stack pointer initial value in there and same some code later setting it up.

There is nothing really magical about the vector table, it is just an address space you can do fetches as well as data cycles.

Two being the minimum, but if you do end up with an alignment fault or other fault then its going to try to find a vector there, if an even number then that's a problem if odd, then try to execute from that address (the lsbit is stripped off the pc does not have an odd number in it, its just a mechanism to indicate thumb vs arm).  So while technically one vector, reset is the minimum its probably a good idea to cover the first 16 (15) just in case.

```
.thumb
.global _start
_start:

.word 0x20001000
.word reset
.word loop
.word loop

.word loop
.word loop
.word loop
.word loop

.word loop
.word loop
.word loop
.word loop

.word loop
.word loop
.word loop
.word loop

.thumb_func
reset:
    b .

.thumb_func
loop:
    b .
```

While you can mix code and vectors if you end up using an interrupt handler for a peripheral then you probably want to not mess with mixing code between the exceptions and wherever your interrupt handler vector is.  If you are really desperate for code space in the flash though then technically you can...

As far as minimum P__J__'s answer is the answer.  I have added this answer to cover the lsbit question.

Comment: wouldn't the disassembly at 8000004 be 0800000c ? (where 'one' is ?)

Comment: the reset handler is at 0x0800000c so the vector in the vector table needs to be 0x0800000c|1 which is 0x0800000d

Comment: that is the point, the address needs to have the lsbit set for the processor to work, if you use the tools right (one) they will do it for you if you dont (two) they wont.

Comment: *There is nothing really magical about the vector table, it is just ram*. Did you mean "rom"? Because AFAIK, vector tables are stored on flash along with `.text`, instead of on the RAM.

Comment: Also, I am under the impression that `_start` is typically used as the entry point, rather than to indicate the beginning of the vector table?

Comment: ... and one more thing: are you intended to form a loop with `bx lr`? It seems like an instruction to return to the calling routine. (Sorry for asking so many questions, but I'm really new)

Comment: yeah that was a mistake was going to come back and fix that those should have been b . not bx lr.   fixed

Comment: when you have an operating system where you have a loader it is not a stretch to then support an entry point into that program and a way to indicate that.  The goal here is to make bytes that you put in a flash, there is no loader and the entry point is defined by the processor logic not an operating system nor tool so _start is not used, just put it somewhere to keep the tool from issuing a warning.

Comment: yes rom, in this application but from arms perspective its just an address space

Answer (score 4):

theoretically you can set only two. the initial stack and the reset handler. If you do not invoke any interrupts (and your program does not end up in the hard fault you do not have to set any

Comment: I do remember one unexpected time when a JLink refused to download my code, and as I recall the JLink software expected a checksum to be placed in a memory location in the vector table. The checksum was stored in one of the Reserved locations. I mention that just in case someone has problems with a very short vector table.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson J-link does not place any data on its own. This comment is not the truth.

Comment: This happened years ago, so it's possible that I am not remembering the exact nature of the problem.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson so what is the reason of your comment? You have just done something wrong.\

Comment: The reason for my comment is that at one time the JLink software would not program a device unless the values in the vector table met certain requirements. I apologize profusely for not being able to remember the specifics, but I thought this might serve as a clue for someone else who was having trouble. My comment was not intended to be a criticism or correction of your answer.